# URL Scheme for opening the iCal app at a date or event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar, icalendar, eventkit

[The Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) gives a nice overview of a number of URL schemes you can use to open certain built-in apps with some parameters.

I know that this is not a complete list of all possible URL schemes that the built-in apps respond to, since there are also ways to [open the system settings](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-settings-app) at various pages. The website http://handleopenurl.com is a nice attempt at gathering all possible URL schemes and it has quite a few built-in apps on there.

One app I would like to open with a URL scheme is the Calendar app (formerly known as iCal). But is there a scheme? If you know there is, please do share (optionally adding it to handleopenurl.com first?). Cheers!

*P.S. Yes, I'm aware of the features of the EventKit(UI) frameworks. But I'd like to specifically open the iCal app.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Probably the Answer is No`**. You need to look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341627/is-there-an-iphone-url-shortcut-for-calendar) and other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752342/how-to-create-add-to-calendar-link-on-web-page-for-iphone) which is marked as accepted so hopefully is true.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any documentation on the parameters, but typing `ical://` into an open browser address bar opens Calendar.app on macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

Note: As far as Apple apps go, this also works with `reminders://`... maybe others

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"calshow://";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```