# Launch my application from default calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I have just added one event on iphone calendar from below code:

```
EKEventStore *store=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) {
            return ;
        }
        EKEvent *event=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title=@"This is the event";
        event.startDate=[NSDate date];
        event.endDate =[event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];
        event.allDay=YES;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        event.URL=url;
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *errr=nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&errr]; //        NSLog(@"%@",errr); //        NSLog(@"%@",event.eventIdentifier);

    }];
```

My event is added to default calendar:
[image]

When you click on event then you will be display this:
[image]

now i want to launch my application from one of the above screen.

Comment: Instead of the google url specify one with a scheme registered by your app.

Comment: try with url schemes you can open your app using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To register an own URL scheme, Apple provides a good documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

To do so, go to your xcode-Project file and select the build target.
Head to "Info". On the bottom there is a dropdown for "URL Types".
The Identifier could match the one, you got for your bundle identifier. The scheme itself is quite important, here you enter the one, you will later use. For example: "myCustomScheme"
[image]

Now bring the app on the device and provide links as followed:
myCustomScheme://additionalURLWithcustomInformation/?andParametersYouWantToUseLater=1234

In the AppDelegate now implement the following method and handle the events:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myCustomScheme"])
    {
        // Custom URL handling, for example for url parameters
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you can pass whatever you want to, but use a custom scheme. E.g. instead of "http://google.com" use "myCustomScheme://google.com". If you want to open the application from the calendar, I would expect the application to handle the correct event I did select. So you could pass the ID of the event or the date. "myCustomScheme://08-04-2014/"

Comment: Thank you @Lepidopternon It helped me, and now i want also do the visa-versa. Means I want to launch the default calendar app of iPhone, then what i should do?

Comment: To go back, you could use the "calshow://" - scheme, described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820762/does-ios-calendar-support-a-url-scheme

Comment: Yups, it works.
But if i want to open calendar with particular EKEvent's object then what i should do?

Comment: Regarding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752342/how-to-create-add-to-calendar-link-on-web-page-for-iphone it is just possible to create calendar events, but not directly open them in the calendar. I'm sorry.