# Launch app from calendar event

Tags: ios, calendar, ekevent, custom-url

I've seen similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930281/launch-my-application-from-default-calendar). But it doesn't work for me. I've added my url scheme with calendar event's url property. It's pretty cool to see scheme url appeared in event's url row. But I couldn't tap on url(url scheme) as like normal url like `www.google.com`.

code for adding url to EKEvent

```
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"Event Test For adding url";
NSString *customURL = @"sampleEventappScheme://";
event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:customURL];
```

After event added to calendar event, see screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

**Note:** If I try to launch app with safari using this scheme, It's perfectly worked. So there's no issue with scheme configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by just extend url by event title with our app url scheme. ie. We just make it as url that is enough.

```
NSString *customURL = @"sampleEventappScheme://title=eventadd";
```

**Brief explanation:**

This is normal url : `http://www.google.com`. Here `http` is url scheme. As like that, in above app url, `sampleEventappScheme` is url scheme. When we try to hit this url, system will see scheme lookup table, if we already register our scheme, then it will switch to our app.